# Confusing Recursive StackOverflowError program

Tags: java, testing, recursion, runtime-error, stack-overflow

I wrote down a recursive program in Java (for fun) where a few things are not clear :

```
public class methodTest
{
    public static double methodTest()
    {
        System.out.println("qwerty") ; // sign that this method is called
        methodTest obj1 = new methodTest() ; // creating an object (perhaps unnessary)
        System.out.println(methodTest.methodTest()) ; // ??!
        return methodTest() ; // returning the same function
    }
}
```

1. Why, if the return datatype is `double`, my BlueJ compiler not showing a syntax error when returning a method ?
2. How can this program be **stopped** if the number of times this method is 'recursed' ***with and without*** using an incrementing variable ?
   [I tried using a static int initialised in the class (before `methodTest()`) and incrementing it in the method but it shows "unreachable statement"]
3. What is the computer doing when it tries to execute the `System.out.println(methodTest.methodTest())` statement ?
4. Why does the compiler give a syntax error (`cannot find symbol - variable obj1`) when I replace (in `System.out.println(methodTest.methodTest())`) `.methodTest` with `.obj1` ?


   Please answer my questions ☝️

Comment: 1. It doesn't return a method; it returns the result of *calling* that method.  2. When do you *want* it to stop?  3. Compilers don't execute code.  4. B/c `obj1` is a local variable, not an instace variable.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case Character

Comment: You are asking many questions in one. That is against Stackoverflow guidelines. The question could be closed by the community because it lacks focus: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question.

Comment: You can split it into creating specific questions one each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to approach this.

Notes:

- The class exposes a simple method that kicks off the recursion.
- The recursive method checks for the number of recursions.
- It returns a hardcoded value because I have no idea what you're actually trying to do.

```java
public class MySampleClass
{
    private static double methodTestPrivate(int callIndex)
    {
       //Check for terminating condition
       if (callIndex >= 10)
           return 42.0;

       //Recursive call
       return methodTestPrivate(callIndex+1);
    }

    public static double methodTest()
    {  
        return methodTestPrivate(0);
    }
}

public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(MySampleClass.methodTest());
    }
}
```

Comment: It'll be easier to stop the recursion if the return value of the method is `void`. then to stop we just have to execute `return;` while returning a number will continue to execute the method over and over again. The variable is still passed through arguments, so no problem there.

Comment: @SuperCoder - huh? I did my best to answer your question based on the example of _your_ code. It looked like you wanted to return a double for some reason so I did that. Perhaps if you explained the actual problem your code was trying to solve, this would make much more sense.

Comment: i'm not criticising yours, this would work too

Comment: thx anyways tho

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not returning a method, you are returning the result of (recursively) calling the method, and the method is defined to return double so all is good
2. There is no real practical way to do it without a counter unless you want to go bananas and use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and count the number of times your method appears in the stack. The simpler way is to pass a counter parameter starting with 0, increment it in any recursive call and add a condition to stop when it reaches your limit (as suggested by RQDQ).
3. It executes `methodTest.methodTest()` and prints its return value
4. Because `methodTest` is a static method and cannot be associated with an instance and `obj1` is an instance.

Comment: to stop the recursion we pass the variable through an argument and turn the recursive function return value to `void` . I think this'll be easier cuz to stop the recursion we just have to pass an incrementing argument in the method and check using an if else whether it passes a certain threshold and pass `return methodTest(i++)` if no and simply `return` when it does. If the method has a return datatype then even if `return 0;` is executed it will continue to work with that.